# C++ inheritance and overriding

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading

I don't understand why the following code does not compile (it is standalone: you can copy/paste it):

```
#include <iostream>

struct Point
{
  float x, y;
};

class Base
{
public:

  virtual bool is_point_inside(float x, float y) const = 0;
          bool is_point_inside(const Point & p ) const { return is_point_inside(p.x, p.y); }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:

  bool is_point_inside(float x, float y) const override { return true; }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  Derived d;

  Point p;
  std::cout << d.is_point_inside(p);

  return 0;
}
```

Does anyone have an explanation?

Comment: Can you include the compiler output?

Comment: Name hiding. Add `using Base::is_point_inside` to fix.